# Render tinymce 4 in a container display:none

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to render tinymce4 on a textarea which is contained in a masked div but I have this error :

```
FontFamily is undefined
```

My render script is :

```
new tinymce.Editor('textarea_id', custom_settings, tinymce.EditorManager).render();
```

You can see the error in this fiddle, when you click on the "render" button :
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/uLfaab

With tinymce 3 I have no problem to do this.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing running code it will be hard for anyone to help you. Perhaps you can make a TinyMCE Fiddle or JS Fiddle that shows the issue?

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thaks for the advice, I add a fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<textarea>` that contains TinyMCE is inside of a non-visible `<div>` then TinyMCE won't be visible either.

If you look at the source of the page (using browser tooling) you will see that TinyMCE is indeed "running" but not visible.

If you want the `<textarea>` to initially be invisible and then become visible when the button is clicked you can do that via JavaScript in your function behind your button.

I have updated your TMCE Fiddle:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/uLfaab/1

There were two changes...

**1 - put an ID on your containing `<div>` so you can easily target it via JavaScript:**

```
<form method="post" action="dump.php">
  <div id="tmceDiv" style="display:none;">
    <textarea id="tmce" name="content" class="mceEditorTxtModif"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

**2 - Use JavaScript to make the containing `<div>` visible:**

```
function test() {
  new tinymce.Editor("tmce", tmce_settings_bureau, tinymce.EditorManager).render();
  // This next line makes the DIV visible!
  document.getElementById('tmceDiv').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to render tinymce before display my div. I have my answer.

Comment: @usualuser Can you please accept the answer so that others know this issue is resolved?